# обработка JSON ответа

Tags: php, javascript, json, json-encode

Есть код

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.domaintally.com/api/v1/whois?access_token=bfb4f4f431f1f366fcff9b30b78fe5d67ee20e97&domain=google.com');
$decode = json_decode($content,true);
var_dump ($decode);
?>
```

выводит он ассоциативный массив с кучей ненужных спец символов, теги '< br>' не отрабатывают,поэтому не могу понять где какой ключ в массиве, чтоб дальше работать с данными

[image: пример вывода]

в чем может быть проблема и как мне привести это в удобочитаемый вид?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем делать var_dump? При json_decode данные из строки преобразуются в объекты и массивы. Скопируйте то что вы получили из сервиса в jsonviewer.stack.hu и составляйте доступ к данным аналогично выданному объекту

```
$JSON = json_decode($content);
$updated_datetime = $JSON->data->{'google.com'}->updated_datetime;
```

Comment: спасибо,разобрался, но непонятно почему тег < br > не работает а отображается как текст:

Comment: примерно так   google.com<br/>Registry Domain ID: 2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN<  br/ >Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com< br/ >Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com< br/ >Updated Date: 2015-06-12T10:38:52-0700< br/ >

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.domaintally.com/api/v1/whois?access_token=bfb4f4f431f1f366fcff9b30b78fe5d67ee20e97&domain=google.com');
$decode = json_decode($content,true);
print_r($decode);
```